# How can I get the user's first and last name by his gmail?

Tags: google-api, google-plus

I am developing an application to work admin.google.com. In my application through Google_Service_Directory I got a users. But I can not understand who it is - I see only gmail. I want by gmail to get the name and surname. How can I do it?

On the Internet, I found answers to the Google Plus library. But Google Plus is closing. What are some other ways to get your first and last name by gmail?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options and they will give you similar information.

**[people get](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get) Google+ api.**

Request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me
```

response:   [people.resource](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people#resource)

```
 "objectType": "person",
 "id": "11720047553265346",
 "displayName": "Linda Lawton",
 "name": {
  "familyName": "Lawton",
  "givenName": "Linda"
```

Note: this call appears on the Google+ api documentation how ever this end point is not being shutdown.  *(waiting for feed back from google on if this is shut down or not.)*

**Userinfo endpoint**

The second option is to call the identity server directly to the userinfo endpoint as described in [OpenIDConnect](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect) requires profile scope i think

**people.get people api**

[people.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get?apix_params=%7B%22resourceName%22%3A%22people%2Fme%22%2C%22personFields%22%3A%22names%22%2C%22fields%22%3A%22*%22%7D) from the people api

request

```
GET https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personfield=names
```

response

```
  "displayName": "Linda Lawton",
  "familyName": "Lawton",
  "givenName": "Linda",
  "displayNameLastFirst": "Lawton, Linda"
```

**Cant search on email**

Note:  This will give you the information on the current logged in user.  There is no way to get back the name of a persona directly by their email address.   Assuming you are running an service account with domain wide delegation you may be able to use people.get with the user id of one of the users on the domain.  I have not tried this

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how do you know that this method (https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me) will not be shutdown?

Comment: Check https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/list the top of the page it stats that the end point is deprecated and will be shut down https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get does not.   Second the blog post they released did not mention this endpoint.

Comment: I just sent an email off to google so we can get a 100% anwser

Comment: @DalmTo, what did Google answer?